# OctoberCMS with JWTAuth API authentication plugin- I am getting {"error":"token_not_provided"}

Tags: octobercms-plugins, jwt, octobercms-user-plugin

I am authenticating users with JWTAuth OctoberCMS API plugin. When I register user or login with postman, the request return a token. However when I try to access authenticated routes like:

```
Route::get('api/v1/todos',
    'Wafush\Maswali\Controllers\Todos@index')->middleware('\Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken');
```

I am getting **{"error":"token_not_provided"}** exception yet the user is authenticated.

Again when I attempt to return signed in user object like:

```
$user = JWTAuth::authenticate();
        return $user;
```

I get the following error:

```
A token is required
C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\plugins\vdomah\jwtauth\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTAuth.php line 299

Type
Undefined

Exception
Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException

    {
        if ($token) {
            return $this->setToken($token);
        } elseif ($this->token) {
            return $this;
        } else {
            throw new JWTException('A token is required', 400);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the request instance.
     *
```

What I am missing. Kindly guide. Its like the token is not getting set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to your question because I was facing the same problem and I've just solved it by adding below code to my .htaccess

> ```
> # Authorization header
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
> RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
> ```

Comment: Found a one-liner: ```# make Authorization header available in october Request headers
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Hi! I think october is blocking all PHP files so the token is not work in the system. so write a couple of lines in htdocs file. so the authorization header is allow token.

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]